# send list (UNICODE) in url Django

Tags: python, django, django-urls

i want to sent the result of a database query in the url. 
The problem is that i can't find a url that matches the result.

i made a function that removes the ( ) characters in the result. 
But at the moment of send it, i get this error.

**Reverse for 'deleteProject' with arguments '(u'Juegos',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['Administration/deleteProject/(?P[-\d]+)$']**

**views.py**

```
def index(request):
    arrayBases = getDatabases(request)
    return render(request, 'index.html', {
        'arrayBases': arrayBases,
    })

def getDatabases(request):
    cursor= connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Administration_proyecto")
    bases = cursor.fetchall()
    arrayBases = []
    for i in bases:
        for j in i:
            arrayBases.append(j)
    return arrayBases

def deleteProject(request, base):
    print request
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
```

**index.html**

```
<table>

  <tr>
  <th>Nombre del proyecto</th>
  <th>Acción</th>
</tr>

{% if arrayBases %}
  {% for base in arrayBases %}
  <tr>
    <td id="{{ base }}"> {{ base }} </td>
    <td>
      <a href="{% url 'deleteProject' base %}">
        <img height="15px" src="{% static "icons/delete.svg" %}">
      </a>
    </td>

  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}

</table>
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^index/$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^deleteProject/(?P<base>[-\d]+)$', views.deleteProject, name="deleteProject"),
]
```

i tried changing the d for a w in the url, but it doesn't works

Comment: Based on your code, this looks like it is a problem with the data in the administration_proyecto table.  Can you please post a few rows of that table?

Comment: This are the rows:       (u'Juegos',)'  (u'PruebaTemp',)'

Comment: that doesn’t look right.  Also, do you have a django model for administration_proyecto or is it a table that you have to access via raw SQL?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your URL endpoint regular expression pattern to:

```
^deleteProject/(\w+)/?$
```

where `(\w+)` is a non-named capturing group that would match one or more alphanumeric characters.